# SQL Statement using Database name pulled from a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Here is my scenario
ParentDB has table with JournalDB Names (I have the select to return the latest JournalDB Name)

```sql
JournalDBName = select top 1 DBName from ParentDB.dbo.JournalNames order by ObjectID desc
```

Trying to run 2nd Select statement where I can "USE" the JournalDBName
similar to

```sql
USE "JournalDBName"
select  
Data1,
Data2,
from JournalRecordLog
```

I'm stuck on passing JournalDBName for "USE" to the 2nd statement.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This isn't how SQL works. This sounds like a design flaw, if i am honest. If you need to dynamically query your databases you *must* use dynamic SQL, but the fact that the data is in different database means that your defining the data as that they are unrelated and should be separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @db   sysname, 
        @exec nvarchar(1000),
        @sql  nvarchar(max);

SELECT TOP (1) @db = DBName 
  FROM ParentDB.dbo.JournalNames 
  ORDER BY ObjectID DESC;

SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

SET @sql = N'SELECT Data1, Data2 FROM dbo.JournalRecordLog;';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```